# Is life experience a necessity to generate mathematical thought?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics

The beginning of mathematics for the Human race was motivated by Human experience. This made me wonder, suppose if there was a concious being existing in deep space devoid of any life experience, would it be logical for it to be able to derive all the mathematical theories we have as of present?

In essence, my question is if the Human experience was a necessity for the creation of modern mathematics or if it was simply a help.

=
Related: [Poverty of Stimulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poverty_of_the_stimulus#:%7E:text=Poverty%20of%20the%20stimulus%20)

Comment: It is hard to imagine that pure thought, without any experience, can produce something.

Comment: To fully address this *seemingly* obvious question you need to tinker about is there anything that which is more fundamental than mathematical thought?...

Comment: You are going to need to include some details about what sort of consciousness it is that you are considering.

Comment: Does thought exist without life?  If not, the life is a prerequisite for any thought, including mathematical sorts.  It seems, though, that the stars across the universe orbit their galactic centers without any concern for whether we give them any "thought" or not, and this makes me suspect that mathematics exists in at least some reasonable sense independent of a thinker.

Comment: strangely worded question which lacks research effort.

Comment: This is essentially the classical debate between _rationalism_ (which sustains experience is contingent) and _empiricism_ (which sustains experience is necessary). Check the [SEP article](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/rationalism-empiricism/).

Comment: The Queen bee. That's all I can say.

Comment: So a charitable interpretation of your question might be “How do practical cognitive faculties contribute to our understanding of mathematics?” And this is a great question - is our sense of things like quantity and logical relation influenced by other things we’ve learned or evolved to be able to do?  There’s some really good material on the development of mathematical cognition, and a pointer to that material would make a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that there is no theory without practice. All theories try to explain how practice works. If there is no practical experience to explain, then there is no theory either.

We experience things with quantifiable properties and we need mathematics to find out how they interact.

The deep void being experiences nothing, interacts with nothing, nothing has any meaning to it. The deep void being does not exist.

Comment: I mean you can engage pure math for the sake of it, however even if you argue with an intrinsic aesthetics of math, that as well is likely a reflection of real world experience.

Answer (score 0):

"inoA"

First, we must define something called life experience

Life is something that a being can feel (I will be more precise at the end)

Before something exists, there must be a law or laws necessary for it

Mathematics is a language to express these laws intelligibly

So the existence of something indicates the existence of its laws

Now we have to define thinking

I know it as putting together the understood data and drawing a conclusion based on it, and the previous findings influence this conclusion, because the intellect is its own creator, even the collected data is also affected by the previous results and data.

And now mathematical thinking

This means examining some laws of existence or trying to understand them

So let's rethink the concept of life experience

Life experience means thinking about these laws of existence because we receive data and analyze them. Hence, life means immediate and constant thinking about laws that can also be expressed as mathematical thinking.

So the answer is: Yes because both are the same

In the end, I apologize for my poor English and inability to convey my meaning exactly

Answer (score 0):

A conscious being existing in deep space devoid of any life experience--you talking about me? In all seriousness, as others have pointed out, life experience can be defined in different ways. I'll just explore one of those here.

Life experience could be defined as any experience involving physical reality. In that case, I don't think that would be necessary for mathematical thought. A pure thinking being could still be capable of recognizing its own existence and intuiting the existence of the number 1 from the fact that there is 1 of itself. As long as it was capable of differentiating between itself and the number 1, it would realize it was contemplating 2 distinct things. The other counting numbers can be similarly derived.

From the relationships of numbers, it could imagine other numbers, such as 1/2 because 1 is 1/2 of 2, 0 because it needs a way to describe none of something, -1 because it needs a way to define a number that adds with 1 to 0, etc. None of this requires physical experience, merely abstract experience with unity and diversity. This is how imaginary numbers were conceived in the human world anyway: it was something to describe the relationships between other numbers, not something required by the physical world, and it only found physical applications later.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and No.
The thought is basically influenced by where you are from.

What mathematician thinks of often is influenced by the tradition of academic institutions.(i.e. Learning mathematics in Kyoto where the center of culture may be different from Tokyo where the economic hub in Japan)

As for generations, mathematics people thought in our time is different from Babylonian time. What people thinks of is regulated by the development of civilization.

Roughly speaking the thought of mathematical thinking is influenced by the time and place.

In some sense, life experience is not so much needed to learn mathematics. Some people are good at intuitively getting essential ideas of the subject.

As for SETI, "Poverty of Stimulus" is not applied since they are not based on this planet.

Answer (score 0):

Your question, as put, is too vague and hypothetical. However, if you want to ponder the role of life experience in the development of mathematical thought then you would do better to consider the development of mathematics on Earth. What you will find if you do, is that culture and society are the dominant forces at play, rather than life experience per se. For hundreds of thousands of years, early humans had life experience, but there is no evidence that they made substantial progress towards the development of what we would now consider mathematics. The development of mathematics is enabled by teaching, by freedom to devote time to the endeavour, by talent and intellect, by having media that allow knowledge to be shared, by having networks of peers to review ideas, and so on.

Yes, it seems reasonable to suppose that some aspects of lived experience played a role in motivating the contemplation of some aspects of mathematics, such as the development of systems to denote the time of the day and the time of the year, which are essentially numerical, or the challenge of assessing quantities, distances, etc, which would have been important to survival. However, animals too share the experience of time and the need to assess distances etc, and there is no evidence that their life experience has led them to develop what we would consider  mathematical.

The necessary conditions for the development of mathematics seem to be sufficient intellectual power coupled with motivation and an enabling society. There is no reason to suppose that humans are the only beings in the Universe endowed with those advantages.

Answer (score 0):

"Mathematics is an intricate fusion of inventions and discoveries. Concepts are generally invented, and even though all the correct relations among them existed before their discovery, humans still choose which ones to study."
[https://www.sfu.ca/~rpyke/cafe/livio.pdf](https://www.sfu.ca/%7Erpyke/cafe/livio.pdf)

(Read the whole article, interesting and robust)

So, from this point of view, it seems that (Human) experience is a necessity for the creation of modern mathematics, in the basis that interaction with reality fuels the "invention" process.